# C++ Template "class type" Errors

Tags: c++, class, templates, compiler-errors, linked-list

I've been working on a linked list template class to do the same thing with a variety of variables, and managed to sort out most of the issues.  Except when I compile, I get these:

```
g++ -Wall -o template_test template_test.cpp
In file included from template_test.cpp:1:0:
LinkedList.h:50:11: error: declaration of ‘class Type’
LinkedList.h:7:11: error:  shadows template parm ‘class Type’
LinkedList.h:51:30: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class LinkedList<Type>’
LinkedList.h:8:7: error: declaration of ‘class LinkedList<Type>’
LinkedList.h:56:11: error: declaration of ‘class Type’
LinkedList.h:7:11: error:  shadows template parm ‘class Type’
LinkedList.h:57:51: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class LinkedList<Type>’
LinkedList.h:8:7: error: declaration of ‘class LinkedList<Type>’
LinkedList.h:92:11: error: declaration of ‘class Type’
LinkedList.h:7:11: error:  shadows template parm ‘class Type’
LinkedList.h:93:31: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class LinkedList<Type>’
LinkedList.h:8:7: error: declaration of ‘class LinkedList<Type>’
LinkedList.h:102:11: error: declaration of ‘class Type’
LinkedList.h:7:11: error:  shadows template parm ‘class Type’
LinkedList.h:103:34: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class LinkedList<Type>’
LinkedList.h:8:7: error: declaration of ‘class LinkedList<Type>’
LinkedList.h:119:11: error: declaration of ‘class Type’
LinkedList.h:7:11: error:  shadows template parm ‘class Type’
LinkedList.h:120:48: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class LinkedList<Type>’
LinkedList.h:8:7: error: declaration of ‘class LinkedList<Type>’
LinkedList.h:158:11: error: declaration of ‘class Type’
LinkedList.h:7:11: error:  shadows template parm ‘class Type’
LinkedList.h:159:37: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class LinkedList<Type>’
LinkedList.h:8:7: error: declaration of ‘class LinkedList<Type>’
LinkedList.h:193:11: error: declaration of ‘class Type’
LinkedList.h:7:11: error:  shadows template parm ‘class Type’
LinkedList.h:194:34: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class LinkedList<Type>’
LinkedList.h:8:7: error: declaration of ‘class LinkedList<Type>’
LinkedList.h:210:11: error: declaration of ‘class Type’
LinkedList.h:7:11: error:  shadows template parm ‘class Type’
LinkedList.h:211:34: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class LinkedList<Type>’
LinkedList.h:8:7: error: declaration of ‘class LinkedList<Type>’
make: *** [template_test] Error 1
```

It pretty much says the same thing for every template function I have.  Can anyone decipher for me what these messages mean, what is causing the compiler to throw these messages, and how do I fix this?  I'll be rereading, and possible rewriting my code in the meantime.
My code is as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class Type>
class LinkedList{
public:

 * default constructor and a copy constructor that creates a copy
 * of the given object*/
LinkedList(); //default construtor
LinkedList(const LinkedList& lst); //copy constructor
~LinkedList();//destructor

void add(Type data);

void insertAt(int pos, Type data);

bool remove(Type data );

void removeAll();

void printList();

template <class Type>
LinkedList<Type>::LinkedList(){
head = NULL;
size = 0; //Don't forget to do this!!!
}

template <class Type>
LinkedList<Type>::LinkedList(const LinkedList& lst){
if (lst.head == NULL){
    head = NULL;
    size = 0;
}
else{
    head = new Node;
    head->data = lst.head->data;
    Node *pNewNode = head;
    Node *pOldNode = lst.head->next;
    while (pOldNode != NULL){
        pNewNode->next = new Node;
        pNewNode = pNewNode->next;
        pNewNode->data = pOldNode->data;;
        pOldNode = pOldNode->next;
    }
    pNewNode->next = NULL;
    size = lst.size;
}
}

template <class Type>
LinkedList<Type>::~LinkedList(){
    removeAll();
}

template <class Type>
void LinkedList<Type>::add(Type x){
Node *p = new Node; //temporary node
// Assign appropriate values to the new node
p -> data = x;
p -> next = head;
// Make the head point to the new node
head = p;   
size++;
}

template <class Type>
void LinkedList<Type>::insertAt(int pos, Type x){
Node *p;
Node *newNode;

// Check that pos is a valid index
if (pos <= size){
    newNode = new Node; //new node
    newNode->data = x;

    // Deal with case when item is to be inserted at the head of the list
    if (pos == 0){
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }// if(pos == 0)
    else{
        p = head;
        // Move to position BEFORE insertion point
        for(int i = 0; i < pos-1; i++){
            // Check that p points to a node
            // Note using exception handling should throw an exception         
            if(p == NULL){
                return;
            }
            p = p->next;
        }//for
        // Insert node
        newNode->next = p->next;
        p->next = newNode;
    }//else (pos != 0)
    size++;
}//else (pos >= size) do nothing
}

template <class Type>
bool LinkedList<Type>::remove(Type x){
Node *p = head;
Node *temp;
if (head == NULL){
    return false;
}
else if (head->data == x){
    head = head->next;
    delete p; //currently assigned head
    size--;
    return true;
}
else{
    while(p->next != NULL){
        // Check next node for target
        if(p->next->data == x){
            temp = p->next;
            p->next = p->next->next;
            delete temp;
            return true;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
}
return false;
}

template <class Type>
void LinkedList<Type>::removeAll(){
Node *p = head;
// Traverse the list deleting nodes
while (p!= NULL){
    head = head->next; // Mustn't "lose" the next node
    delete p; // De-allocate memory
    p = head; // Go to next node
}
head = NULL;
size = 0;
}

template <class Type>
void LinkedList<Type>::printList(){
Node *p = head;
cout << "["; //Nice format!
// Traverse the list
while (p != NULL){
    cout << p -> data; // Print data
    p = p -> next; // Go to next node
    if (p != NULL){
        cout << ","; // Print a comma unless at the end of the list
    }
}
cout << "]"; // Don't print a newline - it might not be wanted
}


private:
struct Node {
    Type data; //list data
    Node *next; //pointer to next item in the list
};

Node *head; //Pointer to the first node in the list
int size; //Records the number of nodes in the list
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the syntax to define a member function outside of the scope of a class *inside* a class. This doesn't work.

This should do it:

```
template<typename X>
class Foo {
public:
  void f();
}; // notice end of class scope here

template<typename X>
void Foo<X>::f() {
  // impl
}
```

Comment: Ah! I see, I should close the linked list class header before I start putting in the "meat".  Should I include the private: portion as well in the class scope before the "meat"?